# How to keep the selected state of UI Selectable until I want to unselected?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, selectable

I just want to hold the selected stated of li until I want to unselected.Just Like my previous question before:

```
        <style>
        #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
        #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
        #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
        #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
        #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
        </style>
        <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
$('#unselect').click(function(event) {
  $('#selectable>li').removeClass('ui-selected');
});
        });
        </script>



    <div class="demo">

    <ol id="selectable">
        <li class="ui-widget-content"><a href="">link can not click</a></li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
    </ol>

    <a href="#" id="unselect">only click me to unselected</a>

    </div><!-- End demo -->
```

**I got `an anchor link` to unselected and the only way to unselected `selected li`**.How can I prevent the selected li to be unselected from other way??

**I found it that the selected li should be unselecte when I click the UL scrollbar if the li list was overflow the UL height.**

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

try this one..

```
$(function() {
            $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
$('#unselect').click(function(event) {
  $('#selectable').find('li').removeClass('ui-selected');  
});
```

Comment: Thanks .but your code as the line I wrote above:$('#selectable>li').removeClass('ui-selected');